# is there a runic font for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: fonts

I would really like a font for the elder futhark runes. I've looked around the site and searched on the net and con find nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Actally offtopic, but here you go: [dafont.com - Dingbats > Runes, Elvish](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=705&page=1)

Answer (score 0):

to add this font to your ubuntu system, paste it in /usr/share/fonts/truetype and update the database:

```
$ sudo su
# cp /path/to/my_font.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype
# fc-cache -f -v
```

Comment: That is not really necessary, just open the file with the default font viewer and click install. It will copy the file to `~.local/share/fonts` and trigger other necessary actions. If you want to make the font files available to all users, I would recommend `/usr/local/share/fonts` instead.